# Prevent NHibernate from adding Returning clause to generated insert statements

Tags: c#, nhibernate, greenplum

I am currently using NHibernate to create entries within my database when pulling data from an API which uses a .NET library to allows interaction with it. I am currently using Greenplum which unfortunately does not support the RETURNING clause (added to the end of the queries generated by NHibernate).

I was wondering if it was possible to suppress the addition of "returning id" to the end of the INSERT statements? As if I were doing something similar in Python with SQLAlchemy (with which I am more familiar), I could do the following to prevent RETURNING clauses from being added:

```
    engine = create_engine(conn_str, implicit_returning=False)
```

Hopefully I have provided enough information, any help would be much appreciated.

Kind regards,

Adam Styles

Comment: Greenplum isn't designed for singleton insert statements so the performance will be poor even if you get around this problem if you are trying to insert very many rows.  You'll want to use gpload to load the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a SQL [dialect](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional-dialects) compatible with your database. The reference documentation may not be complete, have a look to [sources](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/tree/master/src/NHibernate/Dialect) for checking all existing dialects. [greenplum](/questions/tagged/greenplum) does not look to have a dedicated dialect currently.

Since it derives from [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql), you may try to use a PostgreSQL dialect instead. This is already probably what you are doing, but you need to use one that does not claim to support returning inserts ([`Dialect.SupportsInsertSelectIdentity`](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Dialect/Dialect.cs#L822)). `PostgreSQLDialect` does not claim to support it but `PostgreSQL81Dialect` and later do. So try with `PostgreSQLDialect`.

You may instead write and use a dialect for Greenplum, by deriving from the closest suitable existing dialect and then overriding what need to be changed. (You may [contribute](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) it to NHibernate if you wish.)

Notes:

1. This trouble arises when using ids generated db-side on insert, like identity. Using other generator strategies would avoid the trouble too, while having the additional benefit of not triggering an immediate `insert` on `ISession.Save`, thus enabling batching, better unit of work semantic, ...
2. Use a transaction! Otherwise when `Dialect.SupportsInsertSelectIdentity` is disabled, a bug may cause your application to fail retrieving the inserted id. (Seen in multiple forms: [NH-926](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-926), [NH-2145](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2145), [NH-3600](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3600). Alternatively, you may set `connection.release_mode` configuration property to `on_close`.)